# Программно отключить отображение DrawerLayout в определённом фрагменте

Tags: android, kotlin, drawerlayout

Есть активность, в которой используется навигация по фрагментам. В стартовом фрагменте отображается DrawerLayout (кнопка для с изображением ящика, с помощью которого открывается меню) Есть ещё один фрагмент в котором эта же кнопка отображается. Нужно что бы в одном из этих фрагментов эта кнопка перестала отображаться. Как сделать это программно? Или вообще убрать весь toolbar.

Comment: нормальным поведением будет заменить иконку дровера на стрелку назад.
реализация зависит от того какой тулбар вы используете, support или кастомный.

Comment: стрелка назад у меня есть. но она там не нужна. это окно регистрации.